# Proving equivalence of discrete logarithms over a modulus of unknown factorization

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

A prover has a secret exponent $x$, two public bases $g$ and $h$, and a public RSA modulus $N$ of which no party knows the totient/factors. All inputs other than $N$ are coprime with $N$ with overwhelming probability. She publishes $a = g^x\bmod N$ and $b = h^x\bmod N$, but she needs an NIZK that she used the same exponent for both $a$ and $b$. How can she create a proof (assuming access to randomness beacons and commitments)? The proof doesn't need to be truly zero-knowledge as long as finding x is still hard.

This is similar the problem solved by Schnorr's proof of knowledge of a discrete logarithm, but the difference is the RSA modulus, who's factors are unknown and not guaranteed to be safe primes.

Update: A modification of Chaum-Pedersen is used on page 215 of [Shoup 00](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070209-new.pdf) that looks promising. In the context, the RSA modulus is known to be composed of safe primes, but I am unclear as to what the actual requirements are. The paper for [Diogenes](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/374.pdf) claims to apply that method to an RSA number that is composed of primes congruent to $3\mod4$, but it doesn't explain how this is done.

Comment: Quarter-baked idea [update: that does not work, see refutation by poncho]: what if prover made a NIZK proof that they know $x$ with $a\,b^{-1}\equiv(g\,h^{-1})^x\pmod N$?

Comment: I think that Chaum-Pedersen is a more precise analogy than Schnorr. The issue is that we cannot select blinding values and responses uniformly modulo an unknown group order and a significant obstruction to providing a zero-knowledge simulator.

Comment: @DanielS But what if we allow the leaking of trivial information about $x$? $x$ is already a pseudo-random integer that I don't know the exact distribution of yet, but the number of possible values is at least on the order of $2^4096$.

Comment: @Nic That's still a non-zero amount of information and so under the strict definition of zero-knowledge doesn't count. Of course, one can ask a weaker question.

Comment: @DanielS Updated the question.

Comment: @fgrieu: the quarter-baked idea doesn't work; what if they pick $b, x$ arbitrarily, and set $a = b(gh^{-1})^x$...

Comment: That reminds me, in my specific use case, $a$ can later be verified as raised to the "correct" exponent, and $b$ is therefor known to be correct as long as the same exponent was used to find both. Sorry if this makes it an xy problem. Since the answer to my question will still be useful to others, let's try to answer it with out the special conditions I mentioned in this comment.

Comment: What about proving that if we take a generator $g'$ such that $h=g'^y$ and $g=g'^w$ then $ab^{-1}=g^{w+x+y-x}=g^{w-y}=gh^{-1}$? I haven't really thought about it, though.

Comment: I found a paper that seems to have the answer to my question, but I haven't deciphered it yet. The protocol is mentioned on page 214 or 215 of [Shoup 2000](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2000/1807/18070209-new.pdf).

Comment: @JAAAY How do we find a number that we know is a generator if we don’t know the factorization?